# SQL query to find unique Orders with a Quantity of 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called OrderItems.  I want to write a query that returns rows where the quantity = 1, BUT if there are any other records with the same OrderID, I don't want anything returned.

```
Id  OrderID  Qty  SKU
1   123      1    abc123
2   124      2    sho221
3   125      1    toy903
4   125      3    ball05
5   155      1    gree32
```

Using the above example data, I want Order 123 and 155 returned only, because they are for a single SKU with qty of 1.  Order 125 has two SKUs and even though the first one (Id 3) has a qty of 1, the other (Id 4) has a qty of 3, so I don't want those Orders returned.

The query I'm playing with so far is:

```
SELECT o.Id 
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderItems oi
ON oi.OrderId = o.Id 
WHERE oi.Quantity = 1 
GROUP BY eo.Id
```

but this query does not take into account orders that have more than one SKU, just orders that happen to have SKU's with qty of 1.

**In plain English - I want to find orders that only contain a single SKU and of those, they must have qty of one.**

Comment: Query has "oi.OrderId = o.Id" but example shows rows that have different Id vs OrderId

Comment: The Id is just the Identity column and not related to the o.Id column at all.  Sorry if that was confusing.  I just wanted to show that each row is unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could do this also with having:

```
SELECT
  oi.OrderId, 
  sum(oi.Quantity) 
FROM 
  Orders o
  INNER JOIN OrderItems oi
    ON oi.OrderId = o.Id 
group by
  oi.OrderId
having
  sum(oi.Quantity) = 1 and
  count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Your query will return Order ID 125 with ID = 3 which as per OP is not a desired result.

Comment: I just observed OP using Order table. Considering this, to get an desired output you don't need to join with Orders table you can still achieve same result just with OrderItems table. Id column in OrderItems table in question looks like a surrogate key.

Comment: Just curious to know why did you use Count(*) in having. Sum should give the same resut. Is it used to handle negative value cases?

Comment: Yes I added count(*) to get rid of negative and zero records, just in case those can exist

Comment: Good point :). You can edit my fiddle in your answer. I used same data as OP asked. This will help improving answer. Unfortunately I didn't create Order table :)

Comment: I truly appreciate your help JamesZ and Shantanu Gupta!!

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify your SQL Server version, but using a Group Count will remove the need to join back to `OrderItems`:

```
select * 
from
 (
   select *, 
      count(*) over (partition by orderId) as cnt
   from OrderItems
 ) dt 
where cnt = 1 and Qty = 1
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c46f/8)

If this is more efficient depends on the actual data...

Comment: SQL 2014.  Thanks much dnoeth!

Answer (score 2):

Add your Order Quantity for each order no if it is one, thats what you need.
To select any column then you can join again to your orderItem table

```
select * from 
            OrderItems x inner join
            (
                 select orderId, sum(Qty) AS NetQty
                from OrderItems
                group by orderId
               having sum(Qty) =1
             ) t 
on t.orderId = x.orderId
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c46f/2)

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach is to use window functions:

```
select oi.*
from (select oi.*, sum(oi.quantity) over (partition by oi.OrderId) as totqty
      from OrderItems oi
     ) oi
where totqty = 1;
```

That version is nice, because you can easily get all the columns in `OrderItems`.  If you only want the order id:

```
select oi.orderid
from OrderItems oi
group by oi.orderid
having sum(oi.quantity) = 1;
```

The key to both these is that the `join` to `Orders` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `exists` operator to check for additional items of the same SKU

```
SELECT *
FROM   orders a
WHERE  qty = 1 AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   orders b
                   WHERE  a.orderid = b.orderid AND a.id != b.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance:

```
SELECT o.Id 
FROM Orders o
  INNER JOIN OrderItems oi
    ON oi.OrderId = o.Id 
  LEFT JOIN OrderItems oi1
    ON oi.OrderId = oi1.OrderId
       AND oi.Id <> oi1.Id
WHERE oi.Qty = 1 
  AND oi1.id IS NULL
```